# Using sub query result in multiple exist conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get all products based on two conditions on another table. See my example db data.

```
Product
--------------
ProductID     ProductName
1             P1
2             P2
3             P3

AuditLog
------------
Event             Date                 ProductId
ApproveProduct    2016-01-27 16:00     1
ViewProduct       2016-01-27 17:00     1
ViewProduct       2016-01-27 15:00     2
ApproveProduct    2016-01-27 17:00     2
```

Based on the example db data, I would like to get all products that have ViewProduct auditlog entry AFTER ApproveProduct entry based on the Date. I would like to return first product since second product has the AuditLog entries in wrong order:

```
ProductID        ProductName
1                P1
```

I'm trying to achieve something like below, but obviously that code is not valid:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Product p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Date 
FROM AuditLog WHERE Event = 'ApproveProduct' AND ProductId = p.ProductID) ap
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM AuditLog WHERE Event = 'ViewProduct' AND Date > ap.Date AND ProductId = p.ProductID)
```

Comment: The only reason it's not valid is because you've aliased your first subquery in the `WHERE`. You don't alias subqueries in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Are there only 2 rows for each ProductId in AuditLog?

Comment: There can be any amount of rows for ProductId in AuditLog. Only one for event ApproveProduct though for each Product.

Comment: So if there is a row with ViewProduct  before and another one row with ViewProduct after the row with  ApproveProduct, do you want that product in the results?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the `ProductID`s that you want:

```
SELECT ProductId 
FROM AuditLog
GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'ViewProduct' THEN Date END) >
       MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'ApproveProduct' THEN Date END)
```

and also the operator `IN` to get the product details:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE ProductId IN (
  SELECT ProductId 
  FROM AuditLog
  GROUP BY ProductId
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'ViewProduct' THEN Date END) >
         MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'ApproveProduct' THEN Date END)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c402a7e87ae9f3b41f617ed20dfacc86).
Results:

```
> ProductID | ProductName
> --------: | :----------
>         1 | P1
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query should do it

```
select ProductId
from
(
    select
        ProductId,
        Event,
        Lag(Event, 1) over (partition by ProductId order by Date) as PrevEvent
    from AuditLog
    where Event in ('ApproveProduct', 'ViewProduct')
)
where PrevEvent = 'ApproveProduct' and Event = 'ViewProduct'
```

I didn't add a join with the Product table to make the SQL clearer but it should be trivial.